# Android: text from strings.xml displayed as @numbers

Tags: android, string, text

I have updated some string values in strings.xml and my application now shows not the new text but something like @234545201. I have cleaned the projected and rebuilded, there are no import android.R anywhere, just R related to my package. What went wrong?

Comment: show that part of xml

Comment: Please post a sample of code in which you use these strings. Is it XML or Java? Have you tried to run a Project > Clean?

Answer (score 7):

To obtain a string from your `strings.xml` file, you can do a few things.

If you need it as a String object, you can use `getString(R.string.string_id)` to fetch the string, given an ID.

If you're trying to set the text of, say, a `TextView`, you can actually simply use `setText(R.string.string_id)` and the OS will obtain the correct string for you.

In other words, the `TextView` class has a method called `setText(int resid)`, and that's also the reason why you can't write something like the following:

```
TextView.setText(12345680);
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to read it directly as R.string.my_string_resource?
Try passing it to getString() as getString(R.string.my_string_resource).

Answer (score 1):

You can put your stings.xml file in the follwing format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Yamba</string>
<string name="titleYamba">Yamba</string>
<string name="titleStatus">Status Update</string>
<string name="hintText">Please enter your 140-character status</string>
<string name="buttonUpdate">Update</string>
</resources>
```

and use the name as reference of your textbox ids like.

```
 android:text="@string/app_name"
```